# Identifying barricade-looking game

Tags: identify-this-game

When my parents moved, they gave
my old games from their place and there was this game (pieces are just putted like this, no idea if it's supposed to be like that, neither if the orientation is right):

[image: game]

When searching with Google Image, "barricade" is suggested but it's not the same holes.

I think there was a paper with name and rules but it's lost. No memories of playing with it.

No idea if there are missing sticks, neither if some of the one I have are spares.

In France but don't know about the origin of the game.

Comment: I would say google is right. Orientation is correct, first player to reach the top with and you can block other people with your pins.

Comment: That's barricade. Happy to help.

Comment: Unsurprisingly there has been more than one version: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2121481/various-versions-malefiz-barricade

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game is known under Barricade or Malefiz. Your oriantation is correct, the goal is to reach the top.

I would say you are missing a bunch of green pins, in the version I know you have a certain color (usually white) that adds as barricade stones, that are blocking your way to the goal.

As for way you can't find the exact layout on google, there are a lot of different board layouts to this game. In some of them the goal is even in the middle and players are racing from both sides.

You can play this game as well on just a paper with a few coins (since you need to move the barricades around, they are not suited to be just marked on the paper)

I found on google a version that matches your image somehwat

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so it's really a variation of barricade. Now I just have to redo 1 missing blue stick, 2 missing green and I guess the barricades are the black ones, so I need more of them.

Comment: @zigarn as you can see in the Mario version (since it uses the same layout), it has at least 10 blue circles (those are the barricade positions). But they have as well only 6 orange blocks. Might be the smaller game uses less or it is just a demo picture for demonstartions